# How to access the webview in my main activity from a Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-webview

My need is that I have a broadcast receiver and an activity which has a webview. So when receiver receive some event I need to pass some arguments to the webivew or run some JS code. How to do it ?

I am not able to find a way to get access to the webview object in my main activity from receiver.

Comment: do you want to run javascript on your webview or access java objects in java script ?

Comment: Yes I want to run JS code inside webview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to define a broadcast receiver as an inner class in your activity. In the same activity you should have a reference to your WebView that is accessible to the broadcast receiver.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    WebView mWebview;
    BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate() {
    ...
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (mBroadcastReceiver == null) {
        mBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
    }
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        //register broadcast receiver
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        //unregister broadcast receiver
    }
    class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
         @Override
         onReceive(Intent intent) {
             //Receive intent here
             //Call instance of webview
             mWebView.doSomething();
         }
    }
}
```

Also, you'll need to register your broadcast receiver dynamically in the onResume() method of your activity and unregister it in the onPause() method.

Comment: ... but obviously then you have to register and unregister your BroadcastReceiver from the code, not xml

Comment: better onResume/onPause or onStart/onStop as they are "corresponding" pairs

Comment: Is registering of broadcast receiver is not possible in xml ? And when trying to run this code 
ComponentName compName =
                new ComponentName(this,
                        MyReceiver.class);
        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                compName,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

setComponentEnabledSetting is throwing illegalargument-class not found